# bootstrap.js scrollspy with animated scroll

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently using this plugin: http://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav

but would prefer to switch to using Twitter's Bootstrap.js Scrollspy: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy

However, this doesn't offer an option to animate the scroll movement when clicked. How can I add this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should take a look at http://plugins.jquery.com/scrollTo/, it should be faily simple to combine with bootstrap. I will happily give a more detailed explination on how to implement it if you would like.

Comment: A little more help would be great! Where exactly do I put the scrollTo command, e.g. `$.scrollTo('#'+target', 1000);`?

Comment: The scrollspy doesn't handle the movement to the element, this is done natively by the browser. All scroll spy does is change the selected element as the user scrolls. Here is a quick implementation of scrollTo that should help: http://jsfiddle.net/flabbyrabbit/69z7x/

Comment: Brilliant! One final question, can I set a top-offset? Please see here for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/69z7x/5/ So here there'd be a 200px offset.

Comment: Try this: `$.scrollTo(target, 1000, {offset:-200});`

Comment: That takes care of `scrollTo`, but the nav highlight is now 200px out of sync. Any ideas? Thanks for your continued help!

Comment: Found it! Edited the `processScroll` function in `bootstrap-scrollspy.js` to match. Thanks again!

Comment: The way I would do it would be to change `return $(id).offset().top` to `return $(id).offset().top-200` in this.offsets ... but I am sure your solution is just as good

Comment: no need to update any functions, you can just add `data-offset="200"` to the `body`

Answer (score 7):

With or without bootstrap:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-scrollTo/1.4.3/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#yournav').bind('click', 'ul li a', function(event) {
        $.scrollTo(event.target.hash, 250);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: To prevent flickering with scrollspy, add event.preventDefault()

Answer (score 3):

Ok guys, no need to add any extra pointless js plugins.

Add this to body

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-offset="500" data-target="#navbar">
```

Add custom.js to your theme or just use another proper file.

Add this to custom.js

```
// strict just to keep concept of bootstrap
+function ($) {
  'use strict';


// spy and scroll menu boogey
$("#navbar ul li a[href^='#']").on('click', function(e) {

   // prevent default anchor click behavior
   e.preventDefault()

   // store hash
   var hash = this.hash

   // animate
   $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top -500
     }, 1000, function(){
       window.location.hash = hash -500
     })

})

}(jQuery);
```

Be sure you use `<tag id="#myLink"></tag>` and `<a href="#myLink>`

`data-offset="500"` in body and `-500` places in function are to offset place of a scroll

Comment: It not animate for me. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

It's a one liner with [jQuery.localScroll](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.localScroll):

```
$.localScroll();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basically an extension of the answers above but I implemented them slightly differently for a more integrated approach. I don't expect any points for originality but maybe this can help someone.

As mentioned in the answer above, add the scrollTo() script:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-scrollTo/1.4.3/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
```

In the bootstrap.js file find:

```
// SCROLLSPY CLASS DEFINITION
// ==========================
```

In the variable declarations, right under `this.process()` add the variable:
 `this.scroll()`

Then right under the `ScrollSpy.prototype.activate` function, and above:

```
// SCROLLSPY PLUGIN DEFINITION
// ===========================
```

add your scroll() method:

```
ScrollSpy.prototype.scroll = function (target) {
  $('#spyOnThis').bind('click', 'ul li a', function(event) {
      $.scrollTo(event.target.hash, 250);
  });
};
```

This worked for me. Thanks again for helpful advice up above.