# How to add smooth scrolling to Bootstrap's scroll spy function

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, smooth-scrolling

I've been trying to add a smooth scrolling function to my site for a while now but can't seem to get it to work.

Here is my HTML code relating to my navigation:

```
<div id="nav-wrapper">
<div id="nav" class="navbar navbar-inverse affix-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="675">
  <div class="navbar-inner" data-spy="affix-top">
    <div class="container">

      <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>

      <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#service-top">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact-arrow">Contact</a></li>
        </ul><!--/.nav-->
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse collapse pull-right-->
    </div><!--/.container-->
  </div><!--/.navbar-inner-->
</div><!--/#nav /.navbar navbar-inverse-->
</div><!--/#nav-wrapper-->
```

Here is the JS code I've added:

```
<script src="js/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.3.1-min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {

        $('#nav').scrollSpy()
        $('#nav ul li a').bind('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            target = this.hash;
            console.log(target);
            $.scrollTo(target, 1000);
        });
    });
</script>
```

For what it's worth, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711333/bootstrap-js-scrollspy-with-animated-scroll) is where I received info on what I've done so far, and [here](http://homegrowndevelopment.com/) is my site in it's current form.  If you can help me I'll bake you a pie or cookies or something.  Thanks!

Comment: There's also [this jQuery plugin that might make your life easier](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)

Comment: Here's a simple template for Bootstrap 3.x http://www.codeply.com/go/k9CEVobeY6

Answer (score 204, accepted):

Do you really need that plugin? You can just animate the `scrollTop` property:

```
$("#nav ul li a[href^='#']").on('click', function(e) {

   // prevent default anchor click behavior
   e.preventDefault();

   // store hash
   var hash = this.hash;

   // animate
   $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
     }, 300, function(){

       // when done, add hash to url
       // (default click behaviour)
       window.location.hash = hash;
     });

});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FyAnb/86/)

Comment: This works nicely when all links are to anchors in the same page, but if external links are included, they will no longer work. For it to only operate on anchors and leave real links operational use: `$("#nav ul li a[href^='#']").bind('click'').bind(...)` instead.

Comment: nice catch, @Dologan - I edited the result and also changed `bind` to `on`.

Comment: I've got some strange behaviours after implementing this solution: 1) after implementing this code when I open main page (mysite.com/index.php) url changes to smth like this mysite.com/index.php#.Um_weWIyLYA (strange hash automaticly added to url after page loaded); 2) when clicking on menu page scrolls down, but hash in url doesn't change (previously it changes to anchor, i.e. mysite.com/index.php#contacts)

Comment: btw, I use bootstrap 3

Comment: My problem number 1 was not in Bootstrap. AddThis plugin cause that problem. Here is is a solution: http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/1013558-removing-all-hashtags-anchors-weird-codes-from-your-urls#

Comment: @pupadupa: hash doesn't change in the URL because of `e.preventDefault()`. You can add the hash after the animation completes (see edit)

Comment: @onetrickpony now it's give me undefined hash like this mysite.com/index.php#undefined. BTW I've wrap your code with $(document).ready(function() { /*your_c0de_here*/ });

Comment: To solve undefinde problem I do this: 1) add this line `target = this.hash;` before `e.preventDefault();` 2) change line `window.location.hash = this.hash;` to `window.location.hash = target;`

Comment: Just a note that for this to work you'll need to use `<a id="...">` as the anchor instead of the usual `<a name="...">` (though you can add both attributes as a fallback).

Comment: How do you account for extra space for a fixed navbar? `window.location.hash` governs the new url string, and the location. How can you set them independently?

Comment: Probably way easier to add a class to the `a` tags themselves and reference that jQuery selector instead, rather than trying to guess the nesting order of the nav elements.

Answer (score 15):

If you have a fixed navbar, you'll need something like this.

Taking from the best of the above answers and comments...

```
$(".bs-js-navbar-scrollspy li a[href^='#']").on('click', function(event) {
  var target = this.hash;

  event.preventDefault();

  var navOffset = $('#navbar').height();

  return $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - navOffset
  }, 300, function() {
    return window.history.pushState(null, null, target);
  });
});
```

First, in order to prevent the "undefined" error, store the hash to a variable, `target`, before calling `preventDefault()`, and later reference that stored value instead, as mentioned by pupadupa.

Next. You cannot use `window.location.hash = target` because it sets the url and the location simultaneously rather than separately. You will end up having the location at the beginning of the element whose id matches the href... but covered by your fixed top navbar.

In order to get around this, you set your scrollTop value to the vertical scroll location value of the target minus the height of your fixed navbar. Directly targeting that value maintains smooth scrolling, instead of adding an adjustment afterwards, and getting unprofessional-looking jitters.

You will notice the url doesn't change. To set this, use `return window.history.pushState(null, null, target);` instead, to manually add the url to the history stack.

Done!

Other notes:

1) using the `.on` method is the latest (as of Jan 2015) jquery method that is better than `.bind` or `.live`, or even `.click` for reasons I'll leave to you to find out.

2) the navOffset value can be within the function or outside, but you will probably want it outside, as you may very well reference that vertical space for other functions / DOM manipulations. But I left it inside to make it neatly into one function.

Answer (score 8):

```
$("#YOUR-BUTTON").on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#YOUR-TARGET").offset().top
     }, 300);
});
```

Comment: What does this code do? Can you please improve this answer?

Comment: This uses jquery, if you are not using jquery this will not work.

Answer (score 8):

```
// styles.css
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth
}
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp#section2

Answer (score 4):

If you download the jquery easing plugin [(check it out)](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/),then you just have to add this to your main.js file:

```
$('a.smooth-scroll').on('click', function(event) {
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top + 20
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

and also dont forget to add the smooth-scroll class to your a tags like this:

```
 <li><a href="#about" class="smooth-scroll">About Us</a></li>
```

Answer (score 3):

I combined it, and this is the results -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#toTop").hide();

            // fade in & out
       $(window).scroll(function () {
                    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
                        $('#toTop').fadeIn();
                    } else {
                        $('#toTop').fadeOut();
                    }
                });     
  $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
    && location.hostname == this.hostname
    && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
      var $targetId = $(this.hash), $targetAnchor = $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      var $target = $targetId.length ? $targetId : $targetAnchor.length ? $targetAnchor : false;
       if ($target) {
         var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
         $(this).click(function() {
           $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 400);
           return false;
         });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I tested it and it works fine. hope this will help someone :)

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

What `onetrickpony` posted is okay, but if you want to have a more general solution, you can just use the code below.

Instead of selecting just the `id` of the anchor, you can make it bit more standard-like and just selecting the attribute `name` of the `<a>`-Tag. This will save you from writing an extra `id` tag. Just add the smoothscroll class to the navbar element.

**What changed**

1) `$('#nav ul li a[href^="#"]')` to `$('#nav.smoothscroll ul li a[href^="#"]')`

2) `$(this.hash)` to `$('a[name="' + this.hash.replace('#', '') + '"]')`

**Final Code**

```
/* Enable smooth scrolling on all links with anchors */
$('#nav.smoothscroll ul li a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {

  // prevent default anchor click behavior
  e.preventDefault();

  // store hash
  var hash = this.hash;

  // animate
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('a[name="' + this.hash.replace('#', '') + '"]').offset().top
  }, 300, function(){

    // when done, add hash to url
    // (default click behaviour)
    window.location.hash = hash;

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

with this code, the id will not appear on the link

```
    document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]').forEach(anchor => {
        anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href')).scrollIntoView({
                behavior: 'smooth'
            });
        });
    });
```