# Bootstrap scrollspy - how to set offset and smooth transition to each section with Jquery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

What I'd like to do is set the offset for scrollspy as well as give it a smooth transition to each section. I would prefer to not use a plugin or data-attributes (If data-attributes are necessary then ok), but I would like a solution that takes the javascript below and adds the smooth animated scroll effect as well. Jquery solution if possible.

**Scrollspy works and the offset works with this code below:**
Possibly someone can take this code and add to it to set the smooth transition as well?

```
var offset = 60;

    $('.navbar li a').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $($(this).attr('href'))[0].scrollIntoView();
            scrollBy(0, -offset);
    });
```

**My HTML/CSS code is setup as follows:**

I have a container div with the class .main-content. This is set in the css with a margin which offsets it from my header and footer which are fixed top and bottom and have a height of 60px each.

**The CSS for `<div class="main-content"></div>` is as follows:**

```
.main-content {position: realtive; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 60px 0 60px 0;}
```

**I have sections within .main-content and each section has an id="..." and the HTML looks like this. I've removed all content so you can see the sections clearly.**

```
<div class="main-content" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#dl-menu">
    <section id="top" class="top">
        ...
    </section>
    <section id="services" class="services">
        ...
    </section>
    <section id="portfolio" class="portfolio">
        ...
    </section>
    <section id="pricing" class="pricing">
        ...
    </section>
    <section id="faq" class="faq">
        ...
    </section>
    <section id="quote" class="quote">
        ...
    </section>
</div>
```

The menu I'm using has a structure like so:

```
<div id="dl-menu" class="dl-menuwrapper">
    <button class="dl-trigger">Open Menu</button>
    <ul class="dl-menu">
        <li><a href="#top">BACK TO TOP</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services">OUR SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">OUR PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#faq">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#quote">GET YOUR QUOTE</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm quite new to Jquery/JavaScript and have tried every solution I could find, but have not found a solution that works with my layout. If anyone can help me figure this out I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Can you provide us a JsFiddle / Codepen ? I would be happy to give it a try.

Comment: Yes give me a few to get it setup.

Comment: Here is the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/72dygskb/13/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After messing with things from [leuan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3485575/ieuan)'s answer this script started to make sense and I was able to combine some information I found from the link you provided in your answer and this seems to work for the setup I'm using.

```
$(".dl-menu li a[href^='#']").on('click', function(e) {

        // This sets the hash
        var target;
        target = this.hash;

        // Prevent default anchor click behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        // The grabs the height of my header
        var navOffset;
        navOffset = $('#header').height();

        // Animate The Scroll
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - navOffset
        }, 600, function(){

        // Adds hash to end of URL
        return window.history.pushState(null, null, target);

        });

});
```

I want to thank [leuan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3485575/ieuan) for all his help for it was his help that led me to this solution. I hope this works for other people as it did me.

Here is the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/wptjzbno/4/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11814275/3485575) answer.
That answer also states that there is no way to simply change the scroll smoothing done by Bootstrap.

I'd recommend trying a different solution like the code below from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14805098/3485575) answer.

> ```
> $("#nav ul li a[href^='#']").on('click', function(e) {
>
>    // prevent default anchor click behavior
>    e.preventDefault();
>
>    // store hash
>    var hash = this.hash;
>
>    // animate
>    $('html, body').animate({
>        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
>      }, 300, function(){
>
>        // when done, add hash to url
>        // (default click behaviour)
>        window.location.hash = hash;
>      });
>
> });
> ```
>
> [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FyAnb/86/)

Comment: I also tried that, but it did not work. Under the //animate would I replace 'html, body' with my container div? If yes then I've tried that too and does not work. I also read the comments and the few changes mentioned tried those as well. Also that code doesn't set the offset.

Comment: @JeremyBrown setting the offset isn't the problem, you just add that to `$(hash).offset().top` and that should sort itself. There is no way this doesn't work especially if scrollspy works normally

Comment: ok so I tried this and it's scrolling to each section with smooth scroll, but the offset of 60, where do I set that?

Comment: Change `scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top` to `scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top + 60`

Comment: here is the jfiddle with that code and the + 60 added https://jsfiddle.net/er6wg8vk/1/ doesn't work on there either.

Comment: The JSFiddle wasn't set to include jQuery. Also, the offset should be -60 not +60, my bad.
[This](https://jsfiddle.net/Ieuank/wptjzbno/) JSFiddle works flawlessly.

Comment: I just tried your fiddle and when I click on any link it goes up under the header, so it's not working still. =( I also tried that in my code locally and did not make any difference. I'm testing in Firefox. I did test it in Chrome and it works, but not in Firefox.

Comment: @JeremyBrown found the problem. If you remove `window.location.hash = hash;` it works in Firefox too. Firefox forces the default internal linking behavior.

Comment: You're right, the scroll works if you remove that, but the link no longer changes were before it did. Is there a way to fix this so the link continues to change?

Comment: Thanks for all your help leuan, I found a solution and posted it for others, feel free to take a look.